# OSError: [WinError 10022] An invalid argument was supplied in my windows 10 machine

Tags: python, sockets, networking

I am currently learning python and stumbled into an error I can't find the answer to. I am using the latest python version 3.6.4... Hope you can still help me out. This is my classcode:

```
import selectors

sel = selectors.DefaultSelector()

while True:
    events = sel.select(timeout=None)
    for key , mask in events:
        if key.data is none:
            accept_wrapper(key,fileobj)
        else:
            service_connection(key,mask)
```

Comment: You haven't registered any file objects in the selector. What is it supposed to be waiting for?

Comment: See the [example](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/selectors.html#examples) in the documentation for the proper way to use `selector`.